# Generate Razorpay OrderId using FIrebase Cloud Functions for Android App

Tags: android, google-cloud-functions, razorpay

How to generate order ID using the Firebase cloud function for my Android app and send it to the client? The documentation has only the following code and no more details - https://razorpay.com/docs/payment-gateway/android-integration/standard/#step-3-create-an-order-in-your-server

```
  var options = {
  amount: 50000,  // amount in the smallest currency unit
  currency: "INR",
  receipt: "order_rcptid_11"
};
instance.orders.create(options, function(err, order) {
  console.log(order);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of making callback function just use the `async/await`.

Now just make function by using firebase functions.

```
export const createOrder = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    try{
        const order = await instance.orders.create({amount: amount, currency: 'INR', receipt: `${request.id}`, payment_capture: 1});
        res.send(order);
    }catch(e){
        console.log(e);
        res.status(403).send({error: 'Something went wrong'});
    }
});
```